# VBA code not activating cell

Tags: vba, excel

Looks like something wrong with my code. But, I am not able to figure the problem.
I have 2 tabs on workbook. Main sheet and Sub Sheet.
Selecting "yes" in the drop-down on main sheet will enable Sub sheet for entry.
Selecting "No" in the drop-down on main sheet will disable cells on Sub-sheet.

My problem : When I select "No", I dont see the "Active Cell" on any of the sheets. What I mean by Active Cell is the green border we get when we click on cell(Screenshot attached).
[image]

Code on Main Sheet

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.EnableEvents = False
        If Not Intersect(Target, Range("R12")) Is Nothing Then
            If Target.Value = "YES" Then 
                Call Enabler 
            Else 
                Call Disabler
            End If
        End If
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Code on Modules

```
Public Sub Disabler()
     With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SubSheet")
         .Unprotect Password:="xyz"
         .Range("E13:E14").Locked = True
         .Protect Password:="xyz"
     End With
End Sub

Public Sub Enabler()
     With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SubSheet")
         .Unprotect Password:="xyz"
         .Range("E13:E14").Locked = False
         .Protect Password:="xyz"
     End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Add `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SubSheet").Activate` in your `Sub Disabler()` and `Sub Enabler()`.

Comment: What is your excel version?

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following should work for you...

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
On Error GoTo ExitSub
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    If Target.Address <> "$R$12" Then Exit Sub
    If Target.Value = "YES" Then
        Call LockRange(False)
    Else
        Call LockRange(True)
    End If

ExitSub:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub

Private Function LockRange(bFlag As Boolean) As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SubSheet")
        .Unprotect Password:="xyz"
        .Range("E13:E14").Locked = bFlag
        .Protect Password:="xyz"
        'Debug.Print bFlag
    End With
    LockRange = True
End Function
```

Comment: `With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SubSheet")
        .Activate
        .Range("E13").Select
        .Unprotect Password:="xyz"
        .Range("E13:E14").Locked = False
        .Protect Password:="xyz"
     End With` will be better.

Comment: @Flephal. Unfortunately, code you provided doing the same task as mine, that dint help me to find the active cell. When I click on any cell I dont see the green border as screenshot attached earlier. Note: I can edit the cell.

Comment: @Andy Issue still persis :(

Comment: @sady What color is your cell border now?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have to type in:

```
.EnableSelection = xlNoRestrictions
```

BTW you may want to shorten your code by *merging* `Disabler()` and `Enabler()` subs into one Sub:

```
Public Sub DisableSubSheet(disable As Boolean)
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SubSheet")
        .Unprotect Password:="xyz"
        .Range("E13:E14").Locked = disable
        .Protect Password:="xyz"
        .EnableSelection = xlNoRestrictions '<--| make it possible for user to select cells
    End With
End Sub
```

thus, changing your `Worksheet_Change` event handler code as follows:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("R12")) Is Nothing Then
        If Target.Value = "YES" Then
            DisableSubSheet False '<--| in place of previous 'Call Enabler'
        Else
            DisableSubSheet True '<--| in place of previous 'Call Disabler'
        End If
    End If
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```